# How to block one country on Cloudflare Free Plan by using htaccess or other methods?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cloudflare

Im on a shared server. So server side (apache) adjustments may not be work. And also cloudflare ignores our htaccess file.

I have found this code on the web:

```
    if($country_code == 'KW'){
    exit; //or redirect or whatever
}
```

However I dont actually know where to add this code?

I also found this htaccess code which doesnt work(because cloudflare ignores htaccess):

```
    # Block UK
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^(GB)$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</ifModule>
```

So I am stucked on free plan of cloudflare for blocking just one country visitors.
What can I do to block?

Comment: This is not really the easiest thing to do, and you may have to implement several strategies to effectively block the majority of traffic from the undesired location. [Here are a lot of good options for this](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-block-entire-countries-from-accessing-website/). However, it should be noted also that proxies and VPN's can easily get around this, so there is no way to make it 100% effective.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
RewriteEngine On
Deny from 1.1.1.1
```

or for range

```
allow from all
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: No you dont know it see my answer below:

Answer (score 0):

I have found myself:
Actually this code worked:

```
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry RU BuzzOff=1
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=BuzzOff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
# Set the CF-IPCountry header value as "Country" variable
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry "(.*)$" Country=$1

# Than redirect it if the variable match. "VE" for <Venezuela>
RewriteCond %{ENV:Country} VE
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

for your case it would be

```
RewriteEngine on
# Set the CF-IPCountry header value as "Country" variable
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry "(.*)$" Country=$1

# Than redirect it if the variable match. "GB" for <United Kingdom>
RewriteCond %{ENV:Country} GB
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Country codes: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/

Comment: I'm taking the CF-IPCountry from the local variables.

The code that asks where to use is probably the php code.
It is not advisable to do a redirect from there.

To do that you should have previously defined a variable in php.
Example:

$ country_code = $ _SERVER ["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];

Comment: So what is the difference? In my code when I try to enter to site from blocked country it takes a lot of time before entering (Challenging is also activated in cloudflare firewall).

Comment: in my answer was the solution, you were trying to take the cloudflare variables from http and they are in local variables.

Answer (score 0):

In `.htaccess` put your (optimised) country code matcher:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-IPCountry} ^(?:A[BC]|X[YZ])$
RewriteRule ^ blocked-country.php [END]
```

That would match `AB`, `AC`, `XY`, and `XZ`. The reference to the matched country code is in `%0` if you need it.

In `blocked-country.php`:

```
<?php header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 403 Forbidden');?>
Some explanatory message
```